# Finding Permutation Group Block Stabilizers in Polynomial Time

Tags: group-theory, computational-complexity

I have been reading a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10472-009-9171-4) which contains the following claim (in the description of **Algorithm 6**):

If $G$ is a permutation group and and $X_i$ is a non-trivial block-system of $G$, then the block stabilizer ${\rm stab}_G(X_i)$ can be computed in polynomial time (I assume polynomial here means polynomial in $n$ if $G \le S_n$), where ${\rm stab}_G(X_i) = \{g \in G : X_i^g = X_i\}$.

The paper references Holt's *Handbook of Computational Group Theory* to support this claim which I consulted but I still cannot figure out how this algorithm is supposed to work exactly.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Polynomial time means polynomial in the input length unless otherwise specified. The algorithm BlocksStabilizer is on page 107 of the book. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: You're right, I think I just overlooked the algorithm while searching the index. Well, that's embarassing...